# In what way should I frame the question when I have to know whether the tense of all the words in a paragraph are same?

Tags: discussion

Example:

> Condition variable is a variable on the basis of which the threads decide what to do and when to do. This variable is supposed to be shared among the threads, so it is necessary for us to protect it with the mutex.
>       Let there be a variable `temp` shared between two threads. The variable `temp` is called the condition variable
>       ThreadA has to wait for `temp`'s value to become `x` before it can act any further.
>   `temp`'s value is to be edited by threadB, and since it is a global variable, threadB is supposed to lock it.

This is a technical para for sure, but I wish to get all the tenses in one platform here.
Is this kind of question allowed?

Comment: Why not just ask it on the main site and see what happens?

Comment: @FumbleFingers IMO, it is better to know what and how goes on a site first, rather than straight away get into arguments. that's why - asked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be clearer about what question you are actually asking.  "Can this paragraph be made clearer?" is off-topic as proof-reading. "Do all the tenses in this paragraph need to be the same?" is, IMO, not clear enough to answer; how is your paragraph special? Ideally you would say, for example, "Should *is to be* in the last line be just *is* to agree with the earlier *is called* and *has to*?" (NB that is simple enough to be general reference; it's just an example of what I would expect from your title.)

But this is a bit of a grey area regarding on-topic and general reference; as FumbleFingers suggested, you could ask it and see what happens.  If it does get closed, it's not a personal insult, you've just wasted a few minutes.